# Anonymous users can't use refinement panel or paging on custom search page

Tags: 2013, search, anonymous-authentication

I have a custom page in SP 2013 with a search results part and a refinement panel. Everything works fine for authenticated users, but anonymous users get error messages when they click on anything in the refinement panel or when they click to go to page 2 in the search results.

The browser displays the traditional `"something went wrong"`. Fiddler shows that the error message sent from the server is:

> "current user does not have permissions to create a QueryProperties
>   template".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

this should help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d403d030-f5fc-41e9-a41b-ab4154144616/search-does-not-work-for-anonymous-users-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearchprevious

Allow anonymous access in your search center

Answer (score 0):

Enable external sharing with Anonymous users